# How to pipe InputStream to ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, stdin, java-io, wkhtmltopdf, processbuilder

**Please move down to the 2nd update. I didn't want to change the previous context of this question.**

I'm using wkhtmltoimage from a Java app.

The standard way of using it is - `path-to-exe http://url.com/ image.png`.

According to their docs, if we write a `-` instead of an input URL, the input shifts to STDIN.

I'm starting the process using `ProcessBuilder` -

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(exe_path, " - ", image_save_path);

Process process = pb.start();
```

Now I'm unable to figure out how to pipe an input stream to this process.

I have a template file read into a `DataInputStream`, and I'm appending a string at the end:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (new FileInputStream (currentDirectory+"\\bin\\template.txt"));
byte[] datainBytes = new byte[dis.available()];
 dis.readFully(datainBytes);
 dis.close();

 String content = new String(datainBytes, 0, datainBytes.length);

 content+=" <body><div id='chartContainer'><small>Loading chart...</small></div></body></html>";
```

How do I pipe `content` to the `STDIN` of the process?

**UPDATE---**

Following the answer by Andrzej Doyle:

I've used the `getOutputStream()` of the process:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(full_path, " - ", image_save_path);

    pb.redirectErrorStream(true); 

    Process process = pb.start();         

    System.out.println("reading");

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

    bw.write(content);
```

Doing so gives an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended
```

**2nd UPDATE--------**

The current code block is as such:

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(full_path, "--crop-w", width, "--crop-h", height, " - ", image_save_path);
        System.out.print(full_path+ "--crop-w"+ width+ "--crop-h"+ height+" "+ currentDirectory+"temp.html "+ image_save_path + " ");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true); 

        Process process = pb.start(); 
        process.waitFor();
        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
// content is the string that I want to write to the process.

        writer.write(content);
        writer.newLine();  
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Running the above code gives me an `IOException: The pipe is being closed.`

What else do I need to do to keep the pipe open?

Comment: Should you not move pb.start at the end of the program? (after bw.write(content); Just a hunch based on "how do we write to a process after it had started!"

Comment: @Grrrrr well I think we'd need to start a process in order to get its outputstream.

Comment: You are writing data to the outputstream this translates to "your are writing data to the process!" If you want to get the output of the process then you should do process.getInputStream and then read it

Comment: Are you reading the error stream? Perhaps the subprocess is emitting an error and terminating. If you aren't reading the error stream, you'll never know.

Comment: I find `getOutputStream` a very non-explicit name for the actual purpose : *Returns the output stream connected to the normal input of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input of the process represented by this Process object.* In python it's simply called `stdin` but then one could argue that writing to something called `stdin` is not semantically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the whitespace from `" - "` -- the normal whitespaces are removed by the shell parser, but here in the `ProcessBuilder`, it's interpreted as the (literal) filename beginning and ending with a whitespace.

(Actually looking at the process's output as Peter suggested would probably have told you so...)

Answer (score 7):

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended

This means the process you have started has died.  I suggest you read the output to see why. e.g. did it give you an error.

Comment: The process's error stream said the same thing - "The pipe has ended".

Comment: I have never seen a program which gives such an error when run from the command line.

Comment: I found this output from the error: `java.io.BufferedReader@2512b853`

Comment: This means you are printing the BufferedReader object instead of reading it with `readLine()` and printing that out.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason you are using DataInputStream to read a simple text file? From the Java documentation

> A data input stream lets an application read primitive Java data types
>   from an underlying input stream in a machine-independent way

It's possible that the way you are reading the file causes an EOF to be sent to the outputstream causing the pipe to end before it gets to your string.

You requirements seems to be to read the file simply to append to it before passing it on to the wkhtmltoimage process.

You're also missing a statement to close the outputstream to the process. This will cause the process to wait (hang) until it gets an EOF from the input stream, which would be never.

I'd recommend using a BufferedReader instead, and writing it directly to the outputstream before appending your additional string. Then call close() to close the stream.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(full_path, " - ", image_save_path);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process process = null;
try {
    process = pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't start the process.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("reading");

try {
    if (process != null) {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

        BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(currentDirectory+"\\bin\\template.txt")));

        String currInputLine = null;
        while((currInputLine = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(currInputLine);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.write("<body><div id='chartContainer'><small>Loading chart...</small></div></body></html>");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Either couldn't read from the template file or couldn't write to the OutputStream.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String currLine = null;
try {
    while((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(currLine);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't read the output.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you create the `Process` object, you can call [`getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) in order to get hold of a stream that sends its contents to the process' standard input.

Once you have hold of this you can use Java's standard IO to write whatever bytes to the this stream you want (including wrapping it in a Writer, adding buffering, etc.) - and as you write them, they'll be read by the process as soon as they're flushed.

Comment: I'm using the `getOutputStream`, and writing to the process from a buffer. Am I doing it correctly? I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works as well:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/me/stdinecho");
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        Process proc = pb.start();

        // Input file
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream((new FileInputStream("/home/me/stdinecho.cp")));
        byte[] dinBytes = new byte[din.available()];
        din.readFully(dinBytes);
        din.close();
        String content = new String(dinBytes, 0, dinBytes.length);
        content = "header\n" + content + "\nfooter";

        BufferedInputStream procStdout = new BufferedInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
        OutputStream stdin = proc.getOutputStream();

        stdin.write(content.getBytes());
        stdin.flush();
    }

}
```

Here stdinecho.cpp is the program that outputs the line entered on its prompt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strOutput;
    string str;
    while(getline(cin, str)) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}
```